# Python continue from the point where exception was thrown

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, continue

Hi is there a way to continue from the point where exception was thrown?
eg I have the following psudo code

```
unique code 1
unique code 2
unique code 3
```

if I want to ignore the exceptions of any of the unique code statements I will have to do it like this:

```
try:
  #unique code 1
except:
  pass

try:
  #unique code 2
except:
  pass

try:
  #unique code 3
except:
  pass
```

but this isn't elegant to me, and for the life of me I can't remember how I resolved this kind of problem last time... what I want to have is something like

```
try:
  unique code 1
  unique code 2
  unique code 3
except:
  continue from last exception raised
```

UPDATED：
REASON: The reason I am asking about this is the above 3 lines of code share the same kind of exceptions, lets say, extract information from an array, and in this particular scenario I don't really care about the exception of value not in the array.

Comment: using a catch-all exception like that is not a good practice, anyway. You should catch a more specific exception type.

Comment: @Keith I have added reason, please see above.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap each of the code sections into a function and then try calling each in a for-loop:

```
def code1():
    #unique code 1

def code2():
    #unique code 2

def code3():
    #unique code 3

for section in [code1, code2, code3]:
    try:
        section()
    except:
        pass
```

Edit: If your still looking for another way, you could use a decorator to make each call "safe" buy returning any errors instead of throwing them. Not sure if this is really pythonic or a great way to do things but it is a way:

```
def safe_call(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as error:
            return error
    return wrapper

@safe_call
def code1():
    #unique code 1

@safe_call
def code2():
    #unique code 2

@safe_call
def code3():
    #unique code 3

code1()
code2()
code3()
```

Comment: this is a good work around, are there any other more canonical ways?

Answer (score 0):

We can use a **while** loop:

```
#!/urs/bin/env python 

 check = 0
 while True:
     try:
         if check == 0:
             #unique_code_one ()  
             check += 1
         if check == 1:
             #unique_code_two () 
             check += 1 
         if check == 2:
             #unique_code_three() 
     except: 
         check = 2
```

Comment: sorry, I did not read your question carefully. This's wrong answer